# mocking django settings: AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'FOO'

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking, django-settings

Attributes on `settings` disapear after using this:

```
.... here settings.FOO does exist.

with mock.patch('django.conf.settings.FOO', 123, create=True):
    ...

... here settings.FOO is gone.
```

Why does this happen?

I found an old bug, but can't believe that it is still alive, since the bug is four years old:

http://code.google.com/p/mock/issues/detail?id=59

We use mock 1.0.1 from pypi.

Comment: You are trying to do this in test? Maybe you can use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/tools/#overriding-settings or `@override_settings`

Comment: Why I use mock in tests? AFAIK mock was made for testing. I write a library and the library can be configured in many ways. I use mock very often and up to now it worked very well. For me it is easier to use mock than override_settings, since mock works in all python projects (not just django projects).

Comment: My question was about why you are using mock for this case, not for project :) And at this specific case you can use overriding instead of mock, because you are trying to mock django settings.

Comment: @coldmind the mock library is made for mocking everything. Mocking django settings works, except if you use create=True. Then the attribute gets removed after the mock has finished. This should not happen.

Comment: See `UPD` in my answer about `create=True`

Answer (score 2):

Consider simple function:

`testapp/views.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings


def return_settings_foo():
    return settings.FOO
```

Then in shell:

```
In [9]: from testapp import views

In [10]: print views.return_settings_foo()
test

In [11]:
```

Next we will mock settings.FOO:

```
In [11]: with mock.patch('testapp.views.settings.FOO', 'mocked'):
    print views.return_settings_foo()
   ....:     
mocked
```

So, you must mock settings module where you are calling it, (NOT where it is located) for this case it is `testapp/views`.

Test will be the same:

```
import mock

from django.test import TestCase

from testapp import views

class TestPrintFoo(TestCase):
    @mock.patch('testapp.views.settings.FOO', 'mocked')
    def test_print(self):
        result = views.return_settings_foo()
        self.assertEqual(result, 'mocked')

    def test_not_mocked_print(self):
        result = views.return_settings_foo()
        self.assertEqual(result, 'test')
```

---

**UPD**

One more thing. When you use `create=True` on attribute that exists, no matter, if it was existed or not, it will be **deleted** after context end in the `__exit__`, you can use `pdb` to see that. So your FOO attr deleted after context

```
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mock.py(1381)__exit__()
   1380         else:
-> 1381             delattr(self.target, self.attribute)
   1382             if not self.create and not hasattr(self.target, self.attribute):

ipdb> self.target, self.attribute
(<django.conf.LazySettings object at 0x7f48f067db10>, 'FOO')
ipdb>
```

Comment: I don't understand this: `So, you must mock settings module where you are calling it, (NOT where it is located)`. I used the mock library several times this way and it always worked the way I want it to.

Comment: Actually, you have to mock in the way I described. You are importing settings to specific module, so you need to mock settings path in this module, not the *real* path django.conf.settings. It is the normal way, and it's described in every mock tutorial.